# How can create upload Grid/ form in admin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to upload folder of Product images through admin, so how can I create Upload option in admin?

Comment: you need to upload single image for specific product?

Comment: No full image folder for products

Comment: Can you explain what you have try to archive, so I give you sugession according to that.

Comment: I want to create a form, where I can upload the image zip folder and after that, the folder will be in grid format so that we can delete that folder one by one or mass delete. I have createt menu and items for that in admin what to do next?